# Cycle through Linq query

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a LINQ query as follows:

```
Dim CustQuery = From a In db.Customers
                Where a.GroupId = sendmessage.GroupId
                Select a.CustCellphone
```

And would like to go through each result and get the cellphone number to do a peice of code. I have tried the following but cannot seem to get it correct:

```
For Each CustQuery.ToString()
   ...
Next
```

So my question then is how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set a variable in your For Each loop that will store the value of each item in your collection for you to use within your loop.  The correct syntax for a VB For Each loop is:

```
For Each phoneNumber In CustQuery
    //each pass through the loop, phoneNumber will contain the next item in the CustQuery 
    Response.Write(phoneNumber)     
Next
```

Now if your LINQ query was a complex object, you could use the loop in the following way:

```
Dim CustQuery = From a In db.Customers
                Where a.GroupId = sendmessage.GroupId
                Select a

For Each customer In CustQuery
    //each pass through the loop, customer will contain the next item in the CustQuery 
    Response.Write(customer.phoneNumber)     
Next
```